# Improving scrolling behavior in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro, touchpad, scrolling, trello

I use [Trello](https://trello.com/) every single day.  My issue with Trello (which probably isn't specific to Trello, but is the only "example" app I can think of that exhibits this problem) is that the browser window can scroll horizontally between lists and vertically within a list.  This causes much grief for me when I'm using the touchpad on my Macbook Pro.

When using two fingers to scroll up/down a list, my fingers tend to "drift" a little to the left/right.  This results in the list scrolling up/down AND the board scrolling left/right.

I'm highly annoyed by this and I would like to know if there is a way to configure the trackpad or Chrome to "lock" the axis I'm scrolling or (better yet) improve the tolerance with the trackpad so I'm not scrolling everywhere by accident.

Comment: I assume there might be some apps for that, not for chrome, but in general for your os, which would make os ignore little sidescrolls [for specific app?]. Just like this is done on smartphones/tablets. I also assume that such app would be not too hard to make. So, maybe generalize your search a bit?